# Is possible to read multiple large (200mb) xlsx files with 8gb ram in r without using sql?

Tags: r, xlsx

I have multiple (>20) large(>200mb) xlsx files containing a single sheet.
Is it possible to read them without using sql in R?

My computer has a 9th gen i5 and 8gb ram.

Thank you!

The code I used:

```
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
ha.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

I found a packages-Arrow, which is used to handle larger than RAM data. Unfortunately, it seems only support csv..

**Edit:**

I opened the files by excel and transformed them to csv one by one. Then using Arrow::open_dataset to clean the data.

The code is as below:

```
setwd('...') #input path
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(arrow)

file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')

ds <- open_dataset(file.list, format = "csv")

ds %>% glimpse
```

I should write a forloop to transform these files into csv...

Something likes:

```
for (i in 1:length(file.list))
{a = openxlsx::readxlsx(file.list[i])
write.csv(a,'path')
rm(a)
}
```

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried very stupid method: using lapply and parallel computing at the same time... But just now my computer crashed... I need some time to restart my computer and get the code, sorry for lack of information...

Comment: I can't imagine parallel processing is going to be particularly necessary for a few tens of excel files - lapply was probably the right approach but we'd need to see your code and what packages you were using to know more.

Comment: it depends on how much free ram you have. win10 uses up ~3.6 GB Ram on its own. add a few tabs in chrome, rstudio and 1-2 other programs and you may simply not have enough available ram. 20*200mb=4000mb~4gb ram... how much is left before you start working (maybe consider the `disk.frame` library)? -- what happens if you read in a few xlsx files "manually" (not using lapply)? maybe some of them need some extra arguments to be read properly?

Comment: Your question title is misleading. It's 2023. 200 mb is considered small by most people. However, 8 GB RAM is very small. You should check RAM usage by other software (e.g., using the Task Manager).

Comment: I had only 2 gb ram left before starting work... Does it mean that I don't need any extra packages? Just read and wait...?

Comment: no you simply can not read in that amount of data in your ram. [this](https://diskframe.com/) can help you. be aware though that it **may** be unhealthy for your ssd (if you use one)

Comment: I need my computer to Google and write report. Is it possible to decrease the usage of ram used by r? Should I build a sql server...?

Comment: @doraemon Yes, of course you can decrease the RAM usage of R: load less data. If you have to process more data than fits your RAM you'll need to devise strategies to work on chunks of data at the time, rather than all at once. Using SQL Server or another DBS *may* work for this (depending on the operations you want to perform). I think R also has some packages that work with other secondary storage formats (i.e. not a database) but I have no experience with those.

Comment: I found a packages-Arrow, which is used to handle larger than RAM data. Unfortunately, it seems only support csv..

Comment: @doraemon I think you are misunderstanding the point of ‘Arrow’: you can trivially load Excel data (one file at a time) using `read_excel` and store it into an Arrow table. And once all data is converted to Arrow/Parquet format you can then analyse it.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you buy additional RAM. If that is not possible, ask IT for a server instance. If you are doing data analysis, 8 GB physical RAM simply isn't enough.

Comment: I will try my best to convince my boss T^T

Comment: Additional RAM is far less costly than your salary. There are ways to make it work with the RAM you have but it will cost you a lot of developer time.